# Reorder shuffled sequence of integers to match certain criteria (Codewars)

Tags: python, optimization, permutation

I'm a beginner and I am doing some exercises from codewars. This is the description of the exercise:

[Link to the exercise](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5b7bae02402fb702ce000159/train/python)

- Assume we take a number x and perform any one of the following operations:

a) Divide x by 3 (if it is divisible by 3), or

b) Multiply x by 2

- After each operation, we write down the result. If we start with 9, we can get a sequence such as:

[9, 3, 6, 12, 4, 8] -- **9** / 3 = **3** --> 3 * 2 = **6** --> 6 * 2 = **12** --> 12 / 3 = **4** --> 4 * 2 = **8**

- You will be given a shuffled sequence of integers and your task is to reorder them so that they conform to the above sequence. There will always be an answer.
- For the above example:

  `solve([12, 3, 9, 4, 6, 8])` = `[9, 3, 6, 12, 4, 8]`

---

My code passed the first Tests. Then when i tried ATTEMPT (which is the second step and includes many more tests and more complicated tests) my code took to long. There is a time limit of 12000 ms.

**I am looking for hints about how to speed up my code.** (or, which maybe is necessary, how to change the approach to get a faster code)

This is my code:

```py
from itertools import permutations

def solve(arr):

    # First i construct a list of lists of all possible sequences, using permutations.
    perm = [i for i in permutations(arr, len(arr))]
    perm = [list(j) for j in perm]

    # Then i start walking this list until i find a sequence that works.
    for p in perm:

        # for index and elements in the sequence
        for ind, el in enumerate(p[:-1]):

            # I calculate n1, n2: the two possible next numbers in the sequence
            n1 = el/3
            if n1.is_integer():
                n1 = int(n1)
            n2 = el * 2

            # If n1 or n2 isnt the next number in the sequence i break and look 
            # at the next sequence p.
            if (n1 != p[ind+1]) and (n2 != p[ind+1]):
                break
        
        # otherwise i am able to walk the entire sequence 
        # and this means i have found the right one and i can return it
        else:
            return p
```

Comment: The general approach I would take would be more like a selection sort -- given any number there's only one possible number that follows it, right?  So take a number, go find the one that follows it, and move your number before the one that it must follow.  Now find the one that goes after that one, etc.  If one number has nothing that can follow it, that one goes on the end.  Maybe start by dumping the list into a `Counter` so you can look up its contents in O(1) time?  That should make the whole thing O(n).

Comment: @Samwise Thanks! I got this to work. (even without assuming that there's only one possible number that follows it). I started with the max(arr) and worked my way to the end of the sequence, then i worked my way from max(arr) to the beginning of the sequence. I didnt even need to use Counter, but Counters seems really useful so now im off reading about Counters.

Comment: @Samwise If you want to you can post this as an answer which i will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be a bit late to this but seeing as you say you are looking for hints I will leave all the code within spoilers.

First of all, without going into any proofs,

because the only operations are `Divide x by 3` and `Multiply x by 2` and `2` and `3` are primes, once you perform one of these operations you can't return to the original integer, ever.

> The only exception is `0`. It isn't stated in the question but any input list containing `0` would just be a list of zeros. Let's assume `0` will never occur. You definitely can never reach zero using the two operations anyway.

In a sentence I'll say it's because all natural numbers can be expressed as a unique combination of prime factors. Look into prime factorisation for more.

This is **very** important because it means that no digit can appear twice in the sequence. meaning no loops, no repetition and most importantly, there is only one answer (ordered sequence).

Taking advantage of this, you can create a list of all possible pairs of elements.

> `import itertools`
> `input = [12, 3, 9, 4, 6, 8]`
> `# create all permutations of two numbers in the input list`
> `pairs = [i for i in itertools.permutations(input, 2)]`
> `print(pairs)`

```
[(12, 3), (12, 9), (12, 4), (12, 6), (12, 8), (3, 12), (3, 9), (3, 4), (3, 6), (3, 8), (9, 12), (9, 3), (9, 4), (9, 6), (9, 8), (4, 12), (4, 3), (4, 9), (4, 6), (4, 8), (6, 12), (6, 3), (6, 9), (6, 4), (6, 8), (8, 12), (8, 3), (8, 9), (8, 4), (8, 6)]
```

Finding all permutations of two elements from a list isn't actually very slow. For example a list of 40 numbers would only generate 1600 unique pairs. Much fewer than the `1.2089258196e+64` permutations of all 40 numbers.

With these number pairs `(a, b)` we can discard any pairing that doesn't satisfy `a / 3 = b` or `a * 2 = b`

> `# remove any pairs (a,b) that aren't either a/3 = b or a*2 = b`
> `correct_pairs = [(a,b) for (a,b) in pairs  if a/3==b or a*2==b]`

```
[(12, 4), (3, 6), (9, 3), (4, 8), (6, 12)]
```

All that is left over are the exact number of pairs for the *exact* number of operations needed in the sequence. All that is needed is to put them in order. This is the trickiest part.

Suggestion:

> The easiest suggestion is to put these pairs `(a,b)` into a dictionary where `a` is the key and `b` the value of that key. This way looking up any key `a` gives a value `b` that points directly to the next key in the sequence.
> All you have to do first is find the start of the sequence. Then you can just do an iterative search for the next number until you have the sequence.

Code:

> `a_b_dict = {a: b for (a,b) in correct_pairs}`
> `# each pair is in form (a,b)`
> `set_a = set([a for (a, b) in correct_pairs])`
> `set_b = set([b for (a, b) in correct_pairs])`
> `# subtract all numbers from the set of a that are in the set of b. The one number left over will be the start of the sequence`
> `start_of_sequence = set(set_a - set_b).pop()`
> `# add starting sequence number to new list`
> `sorted_numbers = [start_of_sequence]`
> `# remove starting number from dictionary and add the next number in sequence to list`
> `sorted_numbers.append(a_b_dict.pop(start_of_sequence))`
> `# empty dictionaries return False. Loop until a_b_dict is empty. The next key to lookup will be the last element of the current list (index = -1)`
> `while a_b_dict:`
>     `sorted_numbers.append(a_b_dict.pop(sorted_numbers[-1]))`
> `print(sorted_numbers)`

Output:

```
[9, 3, 6, 12, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can significantly increase your program's efficiency by directly iterating through the `permutation` generator.

The reason is because once the program finds a solution, it can break out of the loop, without having to iterate through more unnecessary permutations, like what storing them in a list does:

```
from itertools import permutations

def solve(arr):
    for p in permutations(arr, len(arr)):
        p = list(p)
        for ind, el in enumerate(p[:-1]):
            n1 = el/3
            if n1.is_integer():
                n1 = int(n1)
            n2 = el * 2

            if (n1 != p[ind+1]) and (n2 != p[ind+1]):
                break
        else:
            return p
print(solve([12, 3, 9, 4, 6, 8]) == [9, 3, 6, 12, 4, 8])
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: Thanks! That's much better! Unfortunately it is still timing out, the code is too slow. Maybe this means i have to take another approach all together. Any way this answer was very helpful to me regarding how to work with generators!

Answer (score 1):

Looking through every possible permutation is absolutely the wrong way to solve this.  If you're given 30 items, you'll never go through all 30! possibilities.
There is a much simpler solution.

For each element of the array, find the next value:

```
my_sort = { a : a // 3 if a % 3  == 0 else 2 * a for a in arr}
```

Look though `my_sort`.  You will find that there must be exactly one value in `my_sort.keys()` that isn't anywhere in `my_sort.values()`.  This is your first key.  You know this because each key must be the resulting value of some other key, except for the first one.

```
all_values = set(my_sort.values())
first_key = next(x for x in my_sort.keys() if x not in my_values)
```

Now just generate the list, starting from `first_key`.

The `n!` algorithm is now linear.

=== EDITED ===

This solution is incorrect.  I misunderstood the algorithm.  I thought that 12 *had* to be followed by 4, I didn't realize it could be followed by 4 or 24.

So for each element of the list, let's look at all its possible successors:

```
{12: [4, 24], 3: [1, 6], 9: {3, 18}, 4: [8], 6: [2, 12], 8: [16]}
```

Pruning the lists of successors to be those that are actually in the list:

```
{12: [4], 3: [6], 9: [3], 4: [8], 6: [12], 8: []}
```

At this point, it's clear that your list starts at 9 [nothing has 9 as a successor] and ends at 8 [it has nowhere to go].  You can just read off the answer as 9, 3, 6, 12, 4, 8.

It may turn out that all your test examples are this simple. Alternatively,  there is a little bit more work if every element has a predecessor (you'll just have to try every possibility as the first item) or if some element has two possible successors, you'll have to check both of them.  But your search space is now way smaller.  You're only looking at the permutations that make sense, not all of them.

It may turn out that all of your tests are this simple.

Comment: I think you are on to something that should lead to a solution but if i am not misunderstanding the my_sort is wrong because we dont know if the next value is the result of a division by 3 or a multiplication by 2. It can be either of them. Its not "division if its possible" else "multiplication". Doing my_sort on the test case we get {12: 4, 3: 1, 9: 3, 4: 8, 6: 2, 8: 16}. There are three numbers 12, 9, 6 that are in the keys and not in the values.

Comment: Sorry.  My solution isn't correct.  I just realized I misread the instructions.  I assumed that if `n` was a multiple of 3, then you could **only** go to `n/3`.  Let me think about this for a second. . . .

Comment: No problem! To be fair the instructions they had written were pretty unclear imo. Btw i have found a solution already, see my comment to Samwise. But your ideas should also be a good start for a solution im guessing.